# select count Max(value) with where

Tags: php, mysql

Hello you see in picture attached the table that I want to extract data using this  query

```
SELECT count(idmilestone) 
FROM  milestoneevent 
WHERE max(idmilestone=1)
```

I want to count All the files with last milestone=1    in my case it must return 5  because two files their milestone now is 2 please help me to achieve that

[image]

Comment: why are you using max(idmilestone=1)

Comment: There are 7 `idmilestone=1`, why or how are you getting 5?

Comment: That's because there are 2 `idfile` (1 and 2) that replaces the `idmilestone=1` for `idmileston=2`. So the LAST `idmilestone` of them is 2

Comment: yes but for tow file the last milestone id is 2 so we don't count that

Comment: You have 9 records, 7 have idmilestone = 1. You need to clarify your question.

Comment: I got your point man... 9 records, 7 have idmilestone=1 and we need only those ones which are distinct which makes it 5 (simple...) . Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count('id')
from (select idfile, max(idmilestone) as max_idmilestone
      from milestoneevent
      group by idfile
     ) d
where max_idmilestone = 1;
```

Comment: thanks thats work but why d is this alias necessery

Comment: just you can get result in your own custom label field name. nothing else :)

Comment: Every derived table requires an alias (even if not used)

Answer (score 2):

For the data that you have provided, the milestones are increasing numbers.  If this is generally true, you can simply do:

```
select count(*)
from (select idfile, max(idmilestone) as max_idmilestone
      from milestoneevent
      group by idfile
     ) m
where max_idmilestone = 1;
```

Alternatively, you can use the `dat` to define the last one:

```
select count(*)
from milestonemevent me
where me.dat = (select max(me2.dat)
                from milestonemevent me2
                where me.idfile = me2.idfile
               ) and
      me.idmilestone = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT count(idmilestone) 
FROM  milestoneevent 
WHERE idfile NOT IN(SELECT idfile 
    FROM milestoneevent 
    WHERE idfile > 1)
```

Comment: That's not correct, this query will bring also the idfile 1, which last idmilestone is 2

Comment: not work this return 7   it ,ust return 5 for right query

Comment: You wrote in question "I want to count All the files with last milestone=1"

Comment: what you want how it is come 5 ? what is the logic behind it

Comment: idfile 1 and 2 have a milestone 2, the 5 others don't.

Comment: nico exactly  
Vipin I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

please try this, it will give the count of idmilestone which is the least one i.e 1.

```
SELECT count(idmilestone) FROM  milestoneevent 
WHERE idmilestone =(SELECT MIN(idmilestone) FROM milestoneevent)
```

if you want count which is equal to 1, then try this

```
SELECT count(idmilestone) FROM  milestoneevent 
WHERE idmilestone =1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` for this:

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t1.idfile, t1.idmilestone
FROM milestoneevent AS t1
LEFT JOIN milestoneevent AS t2 
   ON t1.idfile = t2.idfile AND  t1.dat < t2.dat  
WHERE t1.idmilestone = 1 AND t2.id IS NULL
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1865f/2)

To count use `COUNT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM milestoneevent AS t1
LEFT JOIN milestoneevent AS t2 
   ON t1.idfile = t2.idfile AND  t1.dat < t2.dat  
WHERE t1.idmilestone = 1 AND t2.id IS NULL
GROUP BY t1.idfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT idmilestone
    FROM milestoneevent 
    GROUP BY idmilestone
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
WHERE idmilestone=1
```